# Replace multiple strings that start with # in a text with a link

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a long text and within the text, there are numbers that start with #, for example, #23, #8, #123. Each number represents a link. I need to change those numbers with the link. For example, remove #23 with mywebsite.com and #8 with anotherwebsite.com

Comment: How are the links stored - how do you know which number is associated with which link? If it's in a database and the link number is the `id` column - you should just be able to search for that record by the `id` and return the `url` column. If it's a static list - you could set up an associative array with the number as the key and the url as the value.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes, the links are stored in a database. Once I get the number, I plan to run a query to search for the number Id on the database. My problem is how do I get the hashtag number or numbers in the text?

Comment: How are you receiving the numbers currently? or, how do you plan to receive the numbers? For example, will they be sent via a form, or included in a URL which will redirect?

Comment: I will write a text and save the text in a database, within the text instead of writing the entire link, I like to write just the link number with a #, for example, #23 instead mywebsite.com. When the text is viewed, I want the script to change the #23 with mywebsite.com.

Comment: This is not easy to do in MySQL. I suggest you do it in PHP when displaying the results of the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, I'm going to assume you essentially want to replace all instances of numbers like `#12` with a URL that's stored somewhere (database or statically in a variable).

There's a few ways you can do this. I'd suggest either using a regular expression or a direct replacement. If you use a direct replacement, make sure you process each match in "most specific" first (so that `#12` doesn't get replaced by `#1` first).

This example makes a few assumptions but hopefully you can work it into your project.

```php
// declare replacement map
// this could be created from database records
// in that case, you would convert into this key/value structure
$url_map = [
    "1" => "somewebsite.com",
    "2" => "anotherone.com",
    "23" => "google.com",
];

// this could be a value returned from the database
$text = "Some example text (#1) to replace all references #2 with links: #23";

// now we want to replace all matches with their relevant URL
// PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE is important here so that we know
// where in the text to insert the replacement
preg_match_all("/#\d+/", $text, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

// Simplify and reverse.
// We select the first item [0] as we have no capturing groups.
// We reverse so that we can ensure each matched index stays the same.
// If we didn't reverse, we would need to loop, replacing 1 match each
// iteration
$matches = array_reverse($matches[0]);

// process each match
foreach ($matches as $match) {
    $hash = $match[0]; // e.g. #23
    $index = $match[1]; // e.g. 64

    $key = substr($hash, 1); // get number without hash -> e.g. 23
    $url = $url_map[$key];

    $text = substr_replace($text, $url, $index, strlen($hash));
}

echo $text;
// outputs::
// "Some example text (somewebsite.com) to replace all references anotherone.com with links: google.com"
```

Link to documentation:

- [preg_match_all](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)
- [array_reverse](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse)
- [substr_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php)

Comment: You could also do this with capture groups to exclude the `#` from the matches. In that case you would need to subtract `1` from the `$index` to ensure that hash is replaced as well. This would save you from having to use `substr($hash, 1)`

Comment: Wow. Thank you very much for your example and your time. I really appreciated it.